# Select results with a maximum string length

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(30)      | NO   |     |         |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Pretty simple table.
I'm trying to find a way to only select results with a maximum length of 8 characters for a couple of reasons:

1) The HTML table that was created for the record set is too narrow to work with anything greater than 8 characters.

2) We can't have the names truncated when displaying them.

I was looking through the MySQL manual and can't find any solid results. I'm going to try using char_length in the where clause and see what I can come up with and will post back what I find, but I'm hoping somebody has done this before.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just try the char_length function you found in the MySQL docs and then post your question if that didn't work?  From your question, it seems to be the obvious solution and if it doesn't meet your needs you would need to explain why.

Comment: Because this question was not on stackoverflow and I'm sure other people can benefit from it.
I also didn't find the char_length until I finished typing up my question, but decided I would ask anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `CHAR_LENGTH` to get the length of the characters. Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(name) <= 8       -- selects 8 characters or below
-- WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(name) = 8     -- selects exactly 8 characters
```

Additional Info:

`LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in bytes. 
`CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in characters.

```
select length(_utf8 '€') as ByteCount, char_length(_utf8 '€') LengthCount

--  Result
--  ============+==============
--  ByteCount   +   LengthCount
--  ============+==============
--         3    +           1
--  ============+==============
```